# Gridview doesn't display and data doesn't save in DB

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications

I upload files to my directory and that succeeds now i want to get the filename and path to display in my gridview and save just the path to my DB... My problem is that my gridview doesn't display on my web page and nothing saves in the DB please help!

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (FileUpload1.PostedFile != null)
        {

            string FileName = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName.ToString();
            FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("file_folder/" + FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName));
            string strconString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ToolkitdbConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strconString);
            string strQuery = "insert into FileInfo (FileName, FilePath) values(@FileName, @FilePath)";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FileName", FileName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FilePath", "file_folder/" + FileName);
            cmd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
            string[] filespaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\NectarSoft\Projects\Nectarsofttoolkit\Nectarsofttoolkit\file_folder");
            Response.Write("Upload successfull");
            GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: Where you executed query in above code?

Comment: Either you never execute the query or that code snippet is incomplete. Please, double check your question since it useless as it is

Comment: where is GridView1.DataSource property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also before you fetch the data you need to execute the query... then you need to assign a datasource to your Gridview, like `GridView1.Datasource= YourDataSource;` (it can be list or datatable or dataset)

Comment: I added my data source and now i get a new error... sorry i am very new to programming.  Both DataSource and DataSourceID are defined on 'GridView1'.  Remove one definition. i cant see where DataSource ID is defined am i missing something.

Comment: The error doesn't display anymore but my gridview still doesn't display

Comment: You have only executed Insert query (i.e `insert into FileInfo (FileName, FilePath) values(@FileName, @FilePath)"`) Now you need to fetch data using select query (eg `SELECT * FROM FileInfo`) and then bind the records from select query to your GridView [CLICK HERE](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/02/how-to-inserteditupdate-and-delete-data.html) or [CLICK HERE](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Simple-Insert-Select-Edit-Update-and-Delete-in-ASPNet-GridView-control.aspx)for simple example

Answer (score -1):

You need to set the DataSource property of the gridview.

Comment: please add this in comment. please see help in order to answer properly.